# Security Issue: How do I prevent firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword () usage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

The way I set up my signin, I am using firebase auth custom tokens. After 5 tries the account is locked. However there still exists a security flaw.

Suppose a hacker comes along an implements his own javascript file. All he has to do is implement firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword function and try as many email/password combination as he likes and eventually he will be able to get both the username and password. Then from there, sign into my normal system and I would never be able to detect that I was hacked.

I believe I have to implement some sort of firebase security rules for this issue, but I do not know where to start and how to guard the firebase users. Is there a way to stop someone from implementing that function?

I looked at firebase security rules and it shows how to protect the firebase database. But that doesnt work for my purpose. I need it to protect the firebase authentication users.

Comment: well you need to do it at the client side i don't have any idea about firebase dictionary attacks secutiy rules, you need to contact the support directly

Comment: @OussemaAroua thank you. I contacted them, I hope there is a solution...

Comment: as i think for no there is nothing like to prevent this type of attacks, the best choice is to add the security check at the client side and add captcha

Comment: @OussemaAroua i guess. but the prevention of these type of attacks by putting more front end security is useless against someone capable of using this level of attack.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and best solution is simply to disable all sign-in providers in the Firebase Console for your project. Custom auth is always enabled and can't be disabled. 
You need to go to the "Authentication" section -> "SIGN-IN METHOD" -> "Sign-in provider".
https://firebase.corp.google.com/u/0/project/$PROJECT_ID/authentication/providers

If the user tries to create a password account, they will get an error operation-not-allowed.

Comment: thank you, however, I already tried that and it doesnt work. It also ends up disabling my signin as well since I use "firebase.auth.signinwithcustomtoken"

Comment: I just tested. You are incorrect. I disabled email/password in the Console. I was not able to sign-in with an email/password. I was also unable to create a user with email/password. I was able to sign in with custom token.

Comment: @bojeil As the "createCustomToken()" requires user's id (i.e. uid), how can we get the uid if we have disabled the "signInWithEmailAndPassword()" ? For further reference there is a need to decode user back from the custom token.

Comment: You specify the uid. You would need to process your own authentication (email/password, etc without using Firebase), get the associated uid of your own system and then mint a custom token for that uid to sign in with a Firebase user on the client side.